# Как правильно перенести слово "заткнуться"?

Tags: орфография, перенос

Речь о слове "заткнуться". Как правильнее будет его перенести?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Теоретически по современным правилам возможны все варианты переносов:
за-ткнуться, зат-кнуться, затк-нуться, заткну-ться, заткнуть-ся.
Первый и последний - предпочтительнее.

Вопрос о делении на слоги не так очевиден, оно не всегда следует морфологии. Возможен как минимум вариант зат-кну-ться.

Answer (score 1):

Перенос по слогам: за-ткнуть-ся.

Answer (score 0):

заткну-ться
за-ткнуться